# Analyze and reproduce sonic screwdriver sound

Tags: signal-synthesis

Do you know about Doctor Who and its screwdriver?

Well, I'm trying to understand how to replicate [this sound](https://web.archive.org/web/20060112064455/http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/sounds/sonicscrewdriver.mp3) but the spectral analysis is too way complicated, just see its spectrogram.

I was trying to figure out what kind of sine waves or partials it is made of, but probably I have no good experience in this.

I'm writing it in python but for know I have nothing than a signal with two sine waves just to make tests.

How can I understand how this sound is made?
There is a frequency modulation component which I would not consider right now, because it is probably a steady state sound which was modulated later.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
from scipy.signal import get_window
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf



timeLength = 1.0                       # seconds
fs = 44100
t = np.arange(0, timeLength, 1.0/fs)
ww = get_window("hann", t.size)
A = .01
phi = np.pi # phase, radiants.

T = 1.0/fs
df = 20
t_circ = 0.1
t_mid = 0.2
f_mid = 3700
f_circ = df*(1.0 - ((t_circ - t_mid)/t_mid)**2.0)**0.5 
phase1 = np.cumsum((f_mid + f_circ)*T*np.ones(t.size))
phase2 = np.cumsum((f_mid - f_circ)*T*np.ones(t.size))
circ = np.sin(2.0*np.pi*phase1) + np.sin(2.0*np.pi*phase2)


ss = []
#brown_noise = np.random.wald(1, 0.002, len(t))
for i in range(10):
    f = f_mid + 20*i
    s = A * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t + circ) 
    ss.append(s)
ss = sum(ss)
ss = ss/max(ss)



plt.plot(ss)
plt.show()
sf.write('out.wav', ss, fs)
```

Comment: that's a nasty sound.  other than as a sonic weapon, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Just reproduce the sound and have a baseline to use for transformations (angle and pitch shift) like in the episodes

Comment: i dunno python.  but MATLAB can read `.mp3` files.  can python do that?  if not, can python read `.wav` files?  if so, email me and i'll send you the wave.  it's about 140K samples.

Comment: I have already read and analyzed the spectrum. Problem is, how to understand the composition of this sound. Just open it with sonic visualizer for example :)

Answer (score 1):

**An approximation**

Actually, the signal is not that complicated in my opinion. However, I am not a sounds guy... Just playing around with it a bit.

Interestingly, I have a very similar signal that I have produced (see attached sound file and spectrograms. Spectrogram above is my signal (somewhat tuned to your signal's parameters) and below is the sonic screw-driver (of which Doctor by the way? ;) )

I cannot post the code here, since as I said the parameters are a bit tuned to your signal. What I basically did is to create a signal that is...

1. A sum of 10 signals. Center frequency f_mid = 3.7 kHz + 20Hz*N, N = 0, 1, ..., 9, just to have some kind of a wobbly jitter in there
2. The center frequency is modulated by a "circle" (df: maximum change of the center frequency, t_circ: duration of a circle, t_mid: starting point of the circle in time) with df = 20 Hz, t_circ = 0.1s. The phase of the signal is generated from the constant frequency plus the dynamic modulation and a very simple numerical integration (phase multiplied by an increasing dt-vector and cumsuming over it). To get to a signal's frequency, you would differentiate its phase wrt to time - so this is the inverse process.

   `T = 1.0/44100.0
   f_circ = df*(1.0 - ((t_circ - t_mid)/t_mid)**2.0)**0.5 
   phase1 = np.cumsum((f_mid + f_circ)Tnp.ones(t_circ.shape))
   phase2 = np.cumsum((f_mid - f_circ)Tnp.ones(t_circ.shape))
   circ = np.sin(2.0*pi*phase1) + np.sin(2.0*pi*phase2)`
3. Added some somewhat "Brownian" Noise, however it is much below the noise in your signal.

**Things to explore**

- The "duration" of the "circles" seems so vary slightly. Probably sinusoidal variation is also fine, so the period could be jittered.
- Apparently, there is additionally a very broad noise-band. Maybe try some uniform noise with a time-varying windowing?
- Subtract a bunch of short-term, constant frequency signals from your signal. There is a nearly some kind of a grid visible in the spectrogram.

**Some code samples**

I am sorry, in my previous description, I apparently have missed some details. Please find here a code snipped that should be able to produce a basic signal that exhibits the basic "circular" frequency change:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('MacOSX') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
import scipy.signal

# Export function for convenience 
def export_wave2(t, signal_l, signal_r, name = "test_sp.wav"):
    sample_rate = 44100
    data = np.stack((signal_l, signal_r))
    data = np.transpose(data)
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(name, sample_rate, data.astype("float32"))


# Sampling frequency
fs = 44100
T = 1.0/fs

# Circle parameters
t_circ_max = 0.2 # duration of one "circle"
t_circ     = np.arange(0, t_circ_max, 1.0/fs)
t_mid      = t_circ.max()/2.0
f_mid      = 3700 # middle frequency of the sound signal 
df         = 400     # amplitude of the frequency modulation, ie frequency will vary between f_mid - fd and f_mid + fd



# Create ONE circle
f_circ = df*(1.0 - ((t_circ - t_mid)/t_mid)**2.0)**0.5 


phase1 = np.cumsum((f_mid + f_circ)*T*np.ones(t_circ.size))
phase2 = np.cumsum((f_mid - f_circ)*T*np.ones(t_circ.size))
circ = np.sin(2.0*np.pi*phase1) + np.sin(2.0*np.pi*phase2)

# Repeate the circle N times, ie the signal will be N*t_circ_max long
N = 10
circs = np.hstack([circ for k in range(0,N)])
circs = circs / np.abs(circs).max()
circs_time = np.arange(0, N*t_circ_max, 1/fs)

pp.plot(circs_time, circs)
pp.show()

export_wave2(circs_time, circs, circs, name = "test_sp.wav")
```

The frequency behaviour is of course not visible directly in the plots, but when a spectrogram is calculated from *circs*. I have loaded the test_sp.wav into Audacity for this.

[Sound example](https://filebin.net/qrg1ken28bpm2tay/screwdriver.mp3?t=yzkr1o6k)

[image: Spectrograms]

Comment: Thank you for editing my question (I'm not English) and for your answer. Actually It was strange to see that actually there was such solution in order to generate a similar sound. I noticed the modulated sines before but the signal had too much noise and the spectral analysis was difficult. I produced something following your istructions, but in this moment I am stuck on the frequency modulation part. But I think that this is because I need to sleep ( it was such a busy day). Tomorrow I will try again. Then I will add here some results.

Comment: Hey, actually I am a little bit confused on the modulation part (which I think it's my enemy in general). Please can you explain me more about it? I post a code but it's only to show something I tried but in a wrong way.

Comment: I have added code regarding the phase. The phase of the signal is generated via an integration process.

Comment: I am so sorry to say this, but I am very not confident with modulation and first of all I would like to understand the formula, cause I can't figure out what are the parameters. Probably it's just my fault because I can't see obvious things. 

Thank you anyway for your time you dedicated to this.. I updated the code, but I can't understand the formula you use and what parameters like t_circle and t_mid are supposed to be set. See my code, I am doing all wrong?

Comment: Sorry, won’t have much time at the moment. What I can see at the moment: Have a look at circ and not on s or ss.

Comment: No problem, I am stuck but also have no time like you. It was (and I hope I can resolve) an interesting analysis, but now I have to work to my master thesis.

Comment: Have you had a look at the circ variable? This should be the signal your are looking for.

Comment: Yes but it is too much different from your result in the example. It hasn't even the shape. I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out the correct modulation to do

Comment: I am sorry, I've missed a detail myself. Circ of course is the time signal and not the spectrogram. However, I have posted a code snippet in my original post that should produce the basic signal that shows the "circles" in the spectrogram.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will work on this next few days :).
No I wasn't expecting circles in the plot but in the spectrogram, but I did not understood the modulation part. I hope I will do soon. Then I'll write my updates. Thank you for your time.